# Manual third level permanent redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I should redirect pages from old third level to new third level.

http:// esp.site.com/page -> http:// es.site.com/newpage

Is this sintax ok ?

Redirect 301 esp.site.com/page http://es.site.com/newpage

I have to do one to one redirect because there is no rule/relation between old page and new page (third level domain changes: esp -> es)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match host name in `Redirect` directive.

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file of `esp` site:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?esp\.site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/?$ http://es.site.com/newpage [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: I can't do like you say (RewriteCond, RewriteRule) because I have many pages of old website to redirect in single new site. There is no clear rule so I have to redirect manually every url.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment. You may comment `RewriteCond` in above rule though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Old site is very chaotic. There is non clear patter for page So I can't use regular expression. But I should redirect every single to new one in new site. Example:  

esp.site.com / abc -> es.site.com /newpage
esp.site.com / def -> es.site.com /newpage
esp.site.com / ghi -> es.site.com /newpage
esp.site.com / lmn -> es.site.com /newpage


esp.site.com / abc2 -> es.site.com /newpage2
esp.site.com / def2 -> es.site.com /newpage2
esp.site.com / ghi2 -> es.site.com /newpage2
esp.site.com / lmn2 -> es.site.com /newpage2

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.